# .svn folders and files

Tags: svn

My developer has emailed me a compressed folder of the project.  Since he is not  available at the moment, i want to know if the folder he's emailed me contains .svn files or folders.

i want to deploy this folder(project) to the production server so i want to do it without the .svn mess.

At first glance on uncompressing the folder i don't see any .svn file or folder there.

So does that mean it doesn't contain any svn related mess?

And does it also mean that this is a normal copy and not a working copy from my developer's computer or else either he has already rid it off svn  through export or manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no `.svn` folder then, yes there is no subversion technical data (*i.e.*: mess) in the archive. On Unix, Linux or with Cygwin on Windows you can run the following command from the root directory to find and `.svn` dir:

```
find . -name .svn -type d
```

Without Cygwin on Windows you can right click on the root directory, select `Search` type .svn in *search for files or folders named:*, check `Type` in the search options and then select `Folder` in the drop-down menu. Click `Search Now` and *voilà*.

If nothing comes out of this command then there is no subversion technical data in your developer's delivery.

It don't know how the developer did this but he probably did it using the `svn export` command. As this command let you either export from a URL or a working copy there is no way to tell the exact origin of your archive.

Comment: Any way to check on Windows without installing Cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/Mac OS X, you can check for those by running `ls -a` in your shell (e.g. using Terminal). The `-a` flag tells `ls` to show "all" files, including hidden ones (which start with a ".").

You can also use `find . -name ".svn"`, which has the added benefit of recursing into the subdirectories. This might be better for your scenario because the developer might have just deleted the root ".svn" directory and left the subdirectories on accident.

Answer (score 0):

SVN puts a `.svn` folder in each folder of the working copy, so you should make sure that no folder contains a `.svn` subfolder.

To do this in a unix environment do:

```
find . -name .svn
```

If you want to remove them, do

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do note that under Windows, there also exists the option to name those directories _svn to work around OS limitations.

Therefore, unless you know that no Windows came near your sources, to be 100% on the safe side, you will want to check for both .svn and _svn (plain normal file search on the parent folder will find them under any operating system).